Cannot see DBFS option in the catalog section in Databricks Community Edition
When I log into Databricks Community Edition, I no longer see the option to view DBFS files. I was able to access them just last week. I've checked the settings, but I can't find the Admin Console either. I would really appreciate any help in re-enabling these features. Thanks in advance!

Please Mount your AWS S3 bucket
access_key = ""
secret_key = ""
encoded_secret_key = secret_key.replace("/", "%2F")

aws_bucket_name = "yourawsbucketname/"
mount_name = "youraliasmountname"

# #dbutils.fs.unmountf"/mnt/{mount_name}")
dbutils.fs.mount(f"s3a://{access_key}:{encoded_secret_key}@{aws_bucket_name}", f"/mnt/{mount_name}")

After mounting
goto next cell %fs ls /mnt/youraliasmountname


